# spring4 with hibernate4 and springmvc，in DAO obtain Session mode error

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, spring-mvc

The following is my project configuration：
applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="cn.onepiece.module">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice"/>
</context:component-scan>

<!--导入资源文件-->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties"/>

<bean id="stat-filter" class="com.alibaba.druid.filter.stat.StatFilter">
    <property name="slowSqlMillis" value="10000" />
    <property name="logSlowSql" value="false" />
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource">
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>

    <!-- 配置初始化大小、最小、最大 -->
    <property name="initialSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="minIdle" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="20"/>

    <!-- 配置获取连接等待超时的时间 -->
    <property name="maxWait" value="60000"/>

    <!-- 配置间隔多久才进行一次检测，检测需要关闭的空闲连接，单位是毫秒 -->
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="60000"/>
    <!--支持 emoji 4字节 编码-->
    <!--<property name="connectionInitSqls" value="set names utf8mb4;"/>-->
    <!-- 配置一个连接在池中最小生存的时间，单位是毫秒 -->
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="300000"/>

    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 'x'"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="false"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="false"/>

    <!-- 打开PSCache，并且指定每个连接上PSCache的大小 不支持mysql 支持 oracle db2.。 -->
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="false"/>
    <!-- <property name="maxPoolPreparedStatementPerConnectionSize" value="20"
        /> -->
    <!-- 开启监控 -->
    <property name="filters" value="log4j"/>
    <property name="proxyFilters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="stat-filter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--配置sessionFactory-->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="cn.onepiece.module"/>
</bean>

<!--配置事务-->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<contex:component-scan base-package="cn.onepiece.module">
    <contex:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    <contex:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice"/>
</contex:component-scan>

<bean id="velocityViewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutView" />
    <property name="layoutUrl" value="layouts/template.vm"></property>
    <property name="cache" value="false" />
    <property name="prefix" value="templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".vm" />
    <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <property name="toolboxConfigLocation" value="/WEB-INF/vm/toolbox.xml" />
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true" />
    <property name="attributesMap">
        <map>
            <!--Velocity Escape Tool-->
            <entry key="esc"><bean class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.EscapeTool"/></entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="velocityConfig"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:velocity.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

DAO:

```
@Repository("memberDao")
public class MemberDaoImpl implements MemberDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

Error occurred in the getCurrentSession method

```
    exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: createCriteria is not valid without active transaction
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.alibaba.druid.support.http.WebStatFilter.doFilter(WebStatFilter.java:124)

root cause

org.hibernate.HibernateException: createCriteria is not valid without active transaction
    org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.createCriteria(Unknown Source)
    cn.onepiece.module.bbs.member.dao.MemberDaoImpl.findByParam(MemberDaoImpl.java:41)
    cn.onepiece.module.bbs.member.service.MemberServiceImpl.weblogin(MemberServiceImpl.java:49)
    cn.onepiece.module.bbs.member.controller.MemberController.login_post(MemberController.java:31)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.alibaba.druid.support.http.WebStatFilter.doFilter(WebStatFilter.java:124)
```

People know that this is why?

Comment: I put the browser to visit is reported to the wrong written below, you have a look

Comment: Could you share your actual dao method containing the `createCriteria` method call?

Comment: @Override
    public Member findByParam(String username, String password) {
        Session session = getCurrentSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Member.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("nickname", username)).add(Restrictions.eq("password", password));
        return (Member) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }

Comment: And what about the `@Transactional` annotation?

Comment: In DAO layer only <code>@Repository("memberDao")</code> notes, in the service layer <code>@Service("memberService")</code> <code>@Transactional</code> these two notes, and that even if I put <code>@Transactional</code> annotation layer is added DAO, or will be reported before wrong

Answer (score 0):

The properties `<property name="packagesToScan" value="cn.onepiece.module"/>` and `<contex:component-scan base-package="cn.onepiece.module">` in `applicationContext.xml` and `spring-servlet.xml` cause 2 instance of the `@Service` annotated bean.

To avoid this in `spring-servlet.xml` change the `packagesToScan` property to specific package containing the `@Controllers` and other web related beans. for eg.
`<contex:component-scan base-package="cn.onepiece.module.*.*.controller ">`

In  `applicationContext.xml` scan rest of the packages. Do not let the packages scanned to overlap in these two contexts.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking. Tell me your packages for `@Controllers`?

Comment: I'm naming the package name is this ： cn.onepiece.module.*.*.controller